# python return class

Tags: python

I new to python and I read from someone else of the example code below:

```
class A:
  def current(self):
    data = Data(a=a,b=b,c=c)
    return data

class B(A):
  #something here
  #print data a b c
```

How do I print out the data a, b, and c?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you exactly want, but here is a try:

```
class A:
  def current(self):
    data = Data(a=a,b=b,c=c)
    return data

class B(A):
  def print(self):
    data = self.current()
    print "Data A:%s B:%s C:%s" % (data.a, data.b, data.c)
```